# Chrome Extension load Roboto Font

Tags: google-chrome-extension, font-face

I have roboto font which i need to put in my extension.

In my manifest.json file i have mention web_accessible_resources as :

```
"web_accessible_resources": ["fonts/*.ttf"]
```

[image: I have downloaded roboto font .tff file]

Below is css for loading font :

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src:  url('chrome-extension://__MSG_@@extension_id__/fonts/Roboto-Black.ttf') ;
}
/* latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto, sans-serif';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 500;
  src:  url('chrome-extension://__MSG_@@extension_id__/fonts/Roboto-Medium.ttf');
}



/* latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto, sans-serif';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 900;
  src: url('chrome-extension://__MSG_@@extension_id__/fonts/Roboto-Bold.ttf');
}
```

But i can font are not loading when extension content script css loads.

[Google Roboto font url](https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Roboto:300,400,500,700,900&display=swap)

Comment: 1) Try specifying the format explicitly. 2) Try downloading a different type e.g. WOFF. 3) As a last resort, switch to data URI.